# ipcamera /shot.jpg facial recognition with cv2 using python3

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

Lately I've been getting into openCV and tried some facial recognition, I wanted to try it out with video but didn't have a webcam and recording a video didn't seem as fun, so I decided to get the ipcamera app on my phone and get images using the /shot.jpg url. Everything seemed to work but cv2 hasn't been drawing any rectangles.

I am not sure if its a problem with the cascade or if the image is being redrawn before cv2 has a chance to put the rectangles in.

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
import cv2
import numpy as np

def ipCameraFacialRecognition(url,username,password):

    face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
    eye_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_eye.xml')

    while True:
        img_resp = requests.get(url, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(username, password))
        img_arr = np.array(bytearray(img_resp.content), dtype=np.uint8)
        img = cv2.imdecode(img_arr, -1)

        gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

        faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
        for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
            cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)
            roi_gray = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]
            roi_color = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]
            eyes = eye_cascade.detectMultiScale(roi_gray)
            for (ex,ey,ew,eh) in eyes:
            cv2.rectangle(roi_color,(ex,ey),(ex+ew,ey+eh),(0,255,0),2)

        cv2.imshow('img',img)

        if cv2.waitKey(1) == 27:
            break
```

Comment: You can do `print(len(faces))` to see if you found a face and it will be drawn, You can also do `cv2.waitKey(0)` to wait until you hit a key to see if there is any rectangle drawn.

Comment: I figured it out, I didn't think this cascade would have issues with the image being sideways, and ipcamera was sending the video in landscape while i was holding the phone in portrait.